# Linked Lists prints in one computer but not the other

Tags: c, printing, linked-list

Me and my group is currently writing a simple program for an appointment book and i face some problem when i was trying to print the data in the list. Oddly, the program can print the data in the list if i runs it with my computer, and if my group member was trying to run the same code in his/her computer, it can print until the last data in the list and then it crashed. We're using windows 8.1/7 and codeblocks 13.12 and we also tried using unix to run the code but it produce segmentation fault error.

Here is the code that i think is related to the problem

```
typedef struct list
{
    int date_start,date_end;
    // a_time = appointment time
    char a_time[15],what[15],who[15],where[15];
    struct list *next;
}L_LIST;


L_LIST *insert (L_LIST *head_pointer, L_LIST data_in) 
{
   L_LIST *temp = (L_LIST*) malloc (sizeof(L_LIST));

   temp->date_start    = data_in.date_start;
   temp->date_end      = data_in.date_end;
   strcpy(temp->a_time ,data_in.a_time);
   strcpy(temp->what   ,data_in.what);
   strcpy(temp->who    ,data_in.who);
   strcpy(temp->where  ,data_in.where);

   if (head_pointer != NULL) temp->next = head_pointer;
   head_pointer = temp;
   return(head_pointer);
}


void print_list (L_LIST *head_pointer, int mode, char * s_keyword)
{
    int i=1,n_found=0;
    int d_start = atoi (s_keyword);
    while (head_pointer != NULL) {
    if (mode == 1) {
        printf("    %d.   %d-%d %s %s %s %s\n",i,head_pointer->date_start,\
            head_pointer->date_end, head_pointer->a_time,\
            head_pointer->what, head_pointer->who, head_pointer->where);
    }
    else if (mode == 2) {
        if (head_pointer->date_start == d_start) {
            printf("     Found : %d-%d %s %s %s %s\n",head_pointer->date_start,\
                head_pointer->date_end, head_pointer->a_time,\
                head_pointer->what, head_pointer->who, head_pointer->where);
            n_found++;
        }

        else if (strcmp(head_pointer->a_time,s_keyword) == 0) {
            printf("     Found : %d-%d %s %s %s %s\n",head_pointer->date_start,\
                head_pointer->date_end, head_pointer->a_time,\
                head_pointer->what, head_pointer->who, head_pointer->where);
                n_found++;
        }
    }
    else if (mode == 3) {
        FILE* file_pointer = fopen(s_keyword,"a+");
        if (file_pointer == NULL) {
            file_pointer = fopen (s_keyword,"w+");
            fprintf(file_pointer,"\n");
        }

        fprintf(file_pointer,"%d %d %s %s %s %s\n",head_pointer->date_start,\
            head_pointer->date_end, head_pointer->a_time,\
            head_pointer->what, head_pointer->who, head_pointer->where);

        fclose(file_pointer);
    }
    head_pointer = head_pointer->next;
    i++;
    }
}
```

In the print_list function, mode 1 is used for printing all of the data in the list to the screen, mode 2 is for a simple search function and print the matching results on the screen, and mode 3 is for printing the data to a txt file. For mode 2 and 3 it works fine on my computer and on my friends computer, but for mode 1, there is a problem, it works on some computer. I'm not sure what the problem is for the code in mode 1. Or maybe there is something wrong in the list.txt input file ?

```
1 2 10AM Birthday Sister Home
2 2 10AM Birthday Sister Home
3 2 10AM Birthday Sister Home
4 2 10AM Birthday Sister Home
5 2 10AM Birthday Sister Home
```

Thank you for your time :).

Comment: you have a bug(s) in your code.

Comment: @MitchWheat, do you know what is the bug sir? i've been looking at the code but i can't find the bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (head_pointer->date_start == d_start)` ??  Turn on compliers warnings.

Comment: @chux sorry, i forgot to type a line there, it compares the search function keyword and compare it with the data in the list. Thanks

Comment: If it produces a segmentation violation on Unix, have you used a debugger to examine why it occurred...???  Additionally, it may be helpful if you'd post the definition of 'L_LIST`

Comment: Sorry wrong posting.

Comment: @TonyB i have added the L_LIST definition, i hope it helps. About using debugger, i have tried using it by i'm not very good at using it. I will try the debugger again. Thanks

Comment: Suggest verifying the `strcpy()` is not over-filling the destination  (4 places)  `if (strlen(data_in.a_time) >= sizeof(temp->a_time)) Print_ErrorAndExit(); strcpy(temp->a_time ,data_in.a_time);`  (Recommend against `strncpy()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line of code:

```
if (head_pointer != NULL) temp->next = head_pointer;
```

You don't need the "if" statement... just the `temp->next = head_pointer`

If you don't put the "NULL" in the last entry of your list, you won't be able to know when you are at the end.

Comment: it works! Thanks for the input. I never thought about the terminating NULL before, thanks sir. :)